# nPlot dates are appearing as a calculated integer

Tags: r, shiny, rcharts

```
output$plot3 <- renderChart2({
    dat <- candyData[candyData$candyChoice %in% input$candyChoice, ]
    if(!is.na(dat)){ 
      n <- nPlot(freq ~ purchase_month, group = 'candy choice', data=dat, type = "lineChart")
    }
  })
```

My dates, when printed in my console, are shown like this:

```
"2014-04-01" "2014-05-01" "2014-06-01" "2014-07-01" "2014-08-01" "2014-09-01" "2014-10-01"
"2014-11-01" "2014-12-01" "2015-01-01" "2015-02-01" "2015-03-01" "2015-04-01" "2015-05-01"
"2015-06-01" "2015-07-01" "2015-08-01"
```

My dates on the plot are showing up like this:
[image]

Any suggestions on how to fix this would be warmly welcomed!

**Update 2**
The graph lines don't match up with the nPlot interactive tooltip.  Do you know how to fix this?
[image]

Comment: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format your xaxis

```
n$xAxis(tickFormat ="#! function(d) {return d3.time.format('%Y/%m')(new Date(d*1000*3600*24));} !#")
```

Comment: its just how R talks to JS, I think you need this operation to convert datetime objects from R to JS

Comment: Thanks for your help, Pork Chop.  For some reason, the graphs on the chart don't line up with the values on the x-axis.  Do you know how to fix this?  I've attached a photo above to illustrate.  Thanks!

Comment: Tooltop issue is a different question, I think you should create another question as this one is closed and will confuse users